# Annoying to set deployment-token

Tags: environment-variables, appveyor

Currently, i've tried to remove the secured token from the deployment-settings. I don't want to share it on public repositorys.

Here is the default configuration:

```
deploy:
  provider: GitHub
  auth_token:
      secure: **SECUREDTOKEN***
```

I need to set the `secure` part as an **variable**, but nothing work:

```
secure: %AUTH_TOKEN%
secure: "%AUTH_TOKEN%"
secure: $env:AUTH_TOKEN
secure: "$env:AUTH_TOKEN"
secure: $($env:AUTH_TOKEN)
secure: "$($env:AUTH_TOKEN)"
secure: $AUTH_TOKEN
```

I don't want to set the **token** on *appveyor.yml* like
    environment:
      matrix:
        - env:AUTH_TOKEN: "**SECUREDTOKEN***"

I wan't to store it on the Backend, like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can store secure variables in UI settings (on the Backend in your terms), and they will be available during build. You do not need to prefix them with `secure:`, you simple address them using variable name like `%AUTH_TOKEN%`. They are stored in encrypted form, but during build they are decrypted and used as normal variables.

Comment: That's not working; Already tested with some typings like CMD-Based (`%AUTH_TOKEN`), PowerShell-Based (`$env:AUTH_TOKEN`) and other (see my question). When the Deploy-Process starts, it will be canceled with `Error creating GitHub release: Error reading repository '**USER**/**REPO**' releases: 401 - Unauthorized`

Comment: Secure variable set in UI works. You can test it by adding some dummy secure variable, lets say `my_var` in UI and print it's content during build with `- cmd: echo %my_var%` at some step. You will see that value you entered in UI is available during the build. Sure do not do this experiment with API token.

Comment: By the way you do not have to encrypt variable in UI yourself. You just need to press "lock" button to secure it